# Colouring for Wearable ListView Items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Is there a way to change the text colour of list items on Android Wear? I've only previously seen this before and hence done this for phones but don't think the same code can be used for Wear.

**Activity code**

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements WearableListView.ClickListener{

    private WearableListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyColoringAdapter adapter = new MyColoringAdapter(this,listItems);

        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mListView = (WearableListView) stub.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this));
                mListView.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);

            }
        });
    }

    private class MyColoringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MyColoringAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_simple_item_layout, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_simple_item_layout, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            // Set text
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            // Set color depending on position
            int textColorId = R.color.white; // Default color
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    textColorId = R.color.red; break;
                case 1:
                    textColorId = R.color.yellow; break;
                case 2:
                    textColorId = R.color.green; break;
            }
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
            return rowView;
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> listItems;
    static {
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("Item 1");
        listItems.add("Item 2");
        listItems.add("Item 3");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(WearableListView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTopEmptyRegionClick() {

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends WearableListView.Adapter {
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private MyAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public WearableListView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new WearableListView.ViewHolder(
                    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_simple_item_layout, null));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(WearableListView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            TextView view = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            view.setText(listItems.get(position).toString());
            holder.itemView.setTag(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listItems.size();
        }
    }
}
```

**Colouring adapter code**

```
private class MyColoringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MyColoringAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            int textColorId = R.color.white; // Default color
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    textColorId = R.color.red; break;
                case 1:
                    textColorId = R.color.yellow; break;
                case 2:
                    textColorId = R.color.green; break;
            }
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

**Error**

> constructor MyColoringAdapter in class MainActivity.MyColoringAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Context,String[]
>   found: MainActivity,ArrayList
>   reason: actual argument ArrayList cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion

[image]

**Warnings**

For `MyColoringAdapter adapter = new MyColoringAdapter(this,listItems);`

> Variable 'adapter' is never used

Comment: You need to be more detailed about what you have tried and what has happened; in particular give the resulting output to the screen / terminal session / log files.

Comment: @Blackbelt, I did but I get an error that I don't know how to fix. Code has been updated along with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> constructor MyColoringAdapter in class MainActivity.MyColoringAdapter
>   cannot be applied to given types; required: Context,String[] found:
>   MainActivity,ArrayList reason: actual argument ArrayList cannot be
>   converted to String[] by method invocation conversion

the problem is the Constructor of your `ArrayAdpater`. It takes a `String[]` but in your Activity you are passing an `ArrayList<String>`

Change

```
private class MyColoringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MyColoringAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }
```

to

```
private class MyColoringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;

    public MyColoringAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
```

instead of  `textView.setText(values[position]);` you will have  `textView.setText(values.get(position));`.

As side node you should recycle your convertView

Edit: I did notice you have two adapter. But you need one adapter, `MyAdapter`, in you case. Get rid of `MyColoringAdapter`. If you want to change the textcolor, update your onBindView

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(WearableListView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            TextView view = (TextView)   holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            view.setText(listItems.get(position).toString());
            holder.itemView.setTag(position);
            int textColorId = R.color.white; // Default color
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    textColorId = R.color.red; break;
                case 1:
                    textColorId = R.color.yellow; break;
                case 2:
                    textColorId = R.color.green; break;
            }
            view.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
  }
```

Comment: Cool. However I've got a waring `Variable 'adapter'` is never used for `MyColoringAdapter adapter = new MyColoringAdapter(this,listItems);`.

Comment: add listItems to `mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this));`. It should be `mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, listItems));`

Comment: Why do you have two adapters ? I just noticed you have MyAdapter and MyColoringAdapter

Comment: Because I thought a separate adapter is required to change the list item colour

Comment: Error still exists. I've updated my **Activity code**.

Comment: now it is just `mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this));`

Comment: Yeah, just realised that. Thanks for that also. Problem solved. Many thanks.